# Ant build.xml with Deeplearning4j and Lux Delux

Tags: java, ant, deeplearning4j

I'm trying to create an AI for the risk game Lux Delux that will make use of a neural net trained in Deeplearning4j.

Naturally, when I compile I get a bunch of package does not exist errors. How would one go about adding such dependencies to an ant build? Do I need to use Ivy? Build file is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="SillysoftSDK" default="compile" basedir=".">
    <!-- Edit these properties to fit your build environment. 
         Then you will be able to run the 'ant dist' command to re-compile 
         and deploy your file to where Lux will find it. -->
    <property name="built_file" location="build/com/sillysoft/lux/agent/YourClassName.class" />
    <property name="lux_agent_folder" location="${user.home}/Library/Application Support/Lux/Agents/" />
    <property name="lux_mapgen_folder" location="${user.home}/Library/Application Support/Lux/MapGenerators/" />


    <!-- Move your agent class into Lux's agent folder (switch it to lux_mapgen_folder if needed) -->
    <target name="dist" depends="compile">
        <copy file="${built_file}" todir="${lux_agent_folder}"/>
    </target>


    <!-- Clean all build products -->
    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>

    <!-- Compile the java files into their .class files -->
    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="build"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build"
            debug="true" 
            debuglevel="lines,vars,source" 
            includeantruntime="false"
            target="1.7"
            source="1.7" >
        <compilerarg value="-XDignore.symbol.file"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: Please have a look at the [documentation](https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html) to include dependencies as classpath.

Comment: Feel free to join the community on Gitter if you have questions: https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use ant for some reason look at building an uber jar via maven and including it like that.